# TimerTrigger support Ending

Tags: timer-trigger

Can anyone point me to where this announcement is held publicly? I remember getting an e-mail a while ago that stated The TimerTrigger support was ending in 12 months. We do use one and we want to log that we have work to do to change it when not supported. I expect that Microsoft have this announcement logged somewhere and I would like to link to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contacted Microsoft in the end and it is the Azure Scheduler that is losing support. Our case depends on how we have implemented the trigger i.e. is it backed by the scheduler. We will need to take action if it is.